# SQL Server : need help write what i think should be a simple code

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a simple table:

```
id    id_fk    default
--    -----    -------
 1        1          T
 2        1          F
 3        2          T
 4        3          T
 5        3          F
```

I would like to return one row for each `id_fk`. If the default is `T` then return that one. If their is no default `T` then return default `F`.

It seems simple enough but I have been struggling.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and why didn't it work? Isn't this a `MAX` of `default`?

Comment: What if an `id_fk` has two `F`s and no `T`, which one would you choose?

Comment: Along with the problem you should **include the code you have up until this point** (*make some effort to answer your problem/question as [so] is not a code writing service*). After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: The ascii-art table was fine :/

Comment: It is possible to have multiple F but not multiple T, there is also a last updated column that i can order by using your suggestion to return the required record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to filter with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.id = (
    select top(1) t1.id 
    from mytable t1 
    where t1.id_fk = t.id_fk
    oder by t1.default desc, t1.id
)
```

This produces one record for each `id_fk`: priority is given to the record that has `'T'`as `default`, and then to the smalles `id`.

Comment: Thank for you help. This worked on the simple as expected and should work when integrated on the later statement.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this. One possible way is to use the row_number() function for this:

```
select a.*
from
(select x.*,
        row_number() over(partition by x.id_fk order by x.Default desc) as rownum1
from table x) a
where a.rownum1=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id_fk, MAX(default) As default
FROM SimpleTable
GROUP BY id_fk
```